# Android submodule doesn't exist sometimes when I clone repository

Tags: android, git, android-volley

So I added `Volley` as a `submodule` in my `Android Project`. This project is also under version control with `git`.

However, sometimes when I go to work on my project, `Android Studio` complains about `Volley` and I will have to go and re-add the `submodule` to make it work again. Is there something I have to do after I `clone` my repository in order to get `Volley` back into my project? There must be a way I don't know about rather than re-adding the `submodule` everytime I want to work on my project.

Perhaps something similar `npm` where I have to run `npm install` to install dependancies, in this case `submodules`?

Thanks in advance.